# Semantic UI dropdown without icon

Tags: semantic-ui

I am rendering dropdown search input like this:

```
<div class="field">
   <label>Foo</label>
   <select name="foo" class="ui search dropdown">
     <option value="">Choice</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

It creates standard SemanticUI dropdown input.

Is there possibility to tell Semantic to not render any icon or to render different icon in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the alternative method of creating a dropdown (this will need to be intialized by `$('.dropdown').dropdown();`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css">

<h2>Default</h2>
<div class="ui dropdown">
  <div class="text">Foo</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Choice</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>No Icon</h2>
<div class="ui dropdown">
  <div class="text">Foo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Choice</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Custom Icon</h2>
<div class="ui dropdown">
  <div class="text">Foo</div>
  <i class="user icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Choice</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Search Input</h2>
<p>
  Same applies as above: Default, None or Custom icons are allowed
</p>
<div class="ui search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="country">
  <div class="default text">Foo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="af">Choice</div>
  </div>
```

Source: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: This is good answer, however I have small issue, my dropdown input element is now using different style. I just changed my previous code with HTML sample you provideed. http://i.imgur.com/SLSYHJ0.png

Comment: @Kunok I've added search dropdown to my example, it should be similar, but some classes have to be changed, please check it out, and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very for your effort this is exactly what I needed!